# Sphinx-multiversion extension not showing tags/branches on HTML page

Tags: python-sphinx, read-the-docs

I have 2 seperate Github repos, one for documentation and other maintained by developers.

The doc repo (https://gihub.com/doc) does not have any tags, but only local branches.

The actual developer repo (https://github.com/dev) has many tags and branches.

I need to display different tags/releases on my Sphinx `index.html` left navigation bar which basically differentiates the content based on the features developed.

**Current functionality:**

My ReadtheDocs is imported to Github and Readthedocs doc site URL only shows the `latest` version like:

> https://mysite-hosted.com/en/latest/

**My Requirement:**

I need to have something like:

- https://mysite-hosted.com/en/v1.0/
- https://mysite-hosted.com/en/v1.1/

where `v1.0` and `v1.1` should be displayed in the navigation bar.

**What I tried:**

1. I have installed the https://pypi.org/project/sphinx-multiversion/ extension and tried to build the project locally using the command: `sphinx-multiversion . build/html`. On opening the `index.html` page, I don't see any tags/branches displayed on the navigation pane.
2. So, to customize the HTML template, I added the `docs/_templates/versioning.html` file with the below content as per the [documentation](https://holzhaus.github.io/sphinx-multiversion/v0.2.1/templates.html). Still nothing on the navigation.

   ```html
   {% if versions %}
   <h3>{{ _('Branches') }}</h3>
   <ul>
     {%- for item in versions.branches %}
     <li><a href="{{ item.url }}">{{ item.name }}</a></li>
     {%- endfor %}
   </ul>
   <h3>{{ _('Tags') }}</h3>
   <ul>
     {%- for item in versions.tags %}
     <li><a href="{{ item.url }}">{{ item.name }}</a></li>
     {%- endfor %}
   </ul>
   {% endif %}

   <h3>Versions</h3>
   <ul>
     {%- for item in versions %}
     <li><a href="{{ item.url }}">{{ item.name }}</a></li>
     {%- endfor %}
   </ul>
   ```

What am I missing in the steps? What is the right process to see the tags/versions?

Answer (score 0):

Did you setup your `conf.py` like this?

```
html_sidebars = {
'**': ["versioning.html"]
}
```

I am still struggling because the `index.html` does not appear to have the widget in the sidebar!

Comment: Yes, i changed it exactly the same.